# How to find count of odd numbers in digits in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to find the total number of odd values in integers which are elements of an array. For example, the entered array is {113, 220, 235} and the output is:

```
First element has 3 odd numbers.
Second element has 0 odd numbers.
Third element has 2 odd numbers.
```

Till now I have come across the following code.

```
 int optionKS;
 int* arrPtrKS;
 int sizeKS;
 int oddDigitcount;

 cout << "\nWhat is the size of the array? ";
         cin >> sizeKS;
         cout << "\n";
         arrPtrKS = new int[sizeKS];

         for (int i = 0; i < sizeKS; i++) {
             cout << "  Value #" << i + 1 << " ";
             cin >> arrPtrKS[i];
         }

 for (int i = 0; i < sizeKS; i++) {

     while (arrPtrKS[i] > 0) {
         if (arrPtrKS[i] % 2) {
             oddDigitcount++;
         }

         arrPtrKS[i] /= 10;
     }
     
 }
```

The above code gives the total number of odd numbers in the whole array but I'm looking for the number of odd values in each element of the array. I have tried to think of every possible way but still couldn't figure out the solution. What would be the best possible to tackle this issue?

Comment: set `oddDigitcount` to `0` at the beginning of each iteration of the for loop?

Comment: Related: I'd question whether you even need an array, much less a manually-managed dynamic one. When processing a series of values in some fashion (in this case counting odd digits for each value) retaining the values post-read is only required if they're (a) needed later because whatever calculations are dependent to *multiple* values in the series, or (b), the values themselves are later used (such as for sorting, etc). Neither of those apply here. You can simply read a value, count the digits you're interested in, update `oddDigitcount` accordingly, then move to next.

Answer (score 0):

Well you were almost there. oddDigitCount is kept for the whole array. So it is better to keep track of the value in the for loop and print it after each iteration.

(Also use vector to keep track of the values instead of doing your own memory management of arrPtrKS, you didn't do `delete arrPtrKS`.

```
std::vector<int> arrPtrKS {113,220,235};

for (int i = 0; i < arrPtrKS.size(); i++)
{
    int oddDigitcount = 0;
    int originalValue = arrPtrKS[i];
    while (arrPtrKS[i] > 0) 
    {
        if (arrPtrKS[i] % 2) 
        {
            oddDigitcount++;
        }

        arrPtrKS[i] /= 10;
    }     
    std::cout << originalValue << " has " << oddDigitcount << " odd digits" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the logic into a separate function

```
int calculate_odd_digits(int n)
{
  int odd_digits = 0;
  while (n > 0)
  {
    if (n % 2 != 0)
    {
      ++odd_digits;
    }
    n /= 10;
  }
  return odd_digits;
}
```

then you can loop through your array

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeKS; ++i)
{
  std::cout << arrPtrKS[i] " has " << calculate_odd_digits(arrPtrKS[i]) << " odd digits.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you were almost there. In the following piece of code you are counting the odd numbers per element. Only the oddDigitCount is counting for the entire array.

for (int i = 0; i < sizeKS; i++) {

```
 while (arrPtrKS[i] > 0) {
     if (arrPtrKS[i] % 2) {
         oddDigitcount++;
     }

     arrPtrKS[i] /= 10;
 }
```

(The code above this snippet in your post, will just ask you for your input.)

Which means if you create either a vector of maps you could count the odd numbers per element, add them to the map together with the number you were checking. Then you would have a vector containing maps of your numbers with their odd value count.

Just loop through them and print what you'd like to see :)

Remember, the modulo will result you the difference of a division!

PS: Don't forget to garbage collect!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which keeps the count of the number of odd digits in a single number(block of an array).

```
int Coundadd(int n)
{
  int count=0,rem=0;
  while(n)
    {
     rem=n%10;

     if(rem%2!=0){
        count++;
      }
    n=n/10;
    }
  return count;
}
```

This function will calculate the number the of odd digits in a single number.

```
int main()
{
 int OddDigitSum=0,OddNumbers=0;
 int arr[10]={1,3,31,57,923,46,20730,30,111,996};

 for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
 OddDigitSum=OddDigitSum+Coundadd(arr[i]);

 if(arr[i]%2==0){
    OddNumbers++;
 }
 }

  cout<<OddDigitSum<<"\n";
  cout<<OddNumbers<<"\n";

  return 0;
 }
```

The variable OddDigitSum will be calculating the total number of odd digits in all the array.The Variable OddNumbers will be calculating total odd numbers in an array.

The function Coundadd will calculate OddDigitSum.
The answer here will be 16(for  odd digits in all the elements) and 4 (total number of odd numbers) respectively.